# Case-insensitive search of a list in R

Tags: r

Can I search a character list for a string where I don't know how the string is cased?  Or more generally, I'm trying to reference a column in a dataframe, but I don't know exactly how the columns are cased.  My thought was to search `names(myDataFrame)` in a case-insensitive manner to return the proper casing of the column.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Assuming that there are no variable names which differ only in case, you can search your all-lowercase variable name in `tolower(names(myDataFrame))`:

```
match("b", tolower(c("A","B","C")))
[1] 2
```

This will produce only exact matches, but that is probably desirable in this case.

Comment: The searchable package which allows you to turn on case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 74):

I would suggest the `grep()` function and some of its additional arguments that make it a pleasure to use.

```
grep("stringofinterest",names(dataframeofinterest),ignore.case=TRUE,value=TRUE)
```

without the argument `value=TRUE` you will only get a vector of index positions where the match occurred.

Answer (score 20):

With the `stringr` package, you can modify the pattern with one of the built in modifier functions (see `?modifiers). For example since we are matching a fixed string (no special regular expression characters) but want to ignore case, we can do

```
str_detect(colnames(iris), fixed("species", ignore_case=TRUE))
```

Or you can use the `(?i)` case insensitive [modifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

```
str_detect(colnames(iris), "(?i)species")
```

Comment: Also all modifiers from `?stringr::modifiers` have `ignore.case` as the 2nd argument so here for example you can type `str_detect(colnames(iris), fixed("species",ignore_case=TRUE))`

Comment: I looked into `stringr`' s doc and didn't find this behavior documented, where did you get this from ?

Comment: These are fairly standard regular expression modifiers: https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: yes but `grepl` doesn't  seem to support them so I assumed it was coded into `stringr` or `stringi`

Comment: `grepl` does with `perl=TRUE`: `grepl("(?i)species", colnames(iris), perl=TRUE)`

Comment: My bad, actually `grepl("(?i)species",colnames(iris))` works, but `grepl("(?x)S pecies",colnames(iris))` doesn't while `grepl("(?x)S pecies",colnames(iris), perl=TRUE)` does.

Comment: This lead me to post this bounty : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47240375/regular-expressions-in-base-r-perl-true-vs-the-default-pcre-vs-tre

Answer (score 7):

For anyone using this with `%in%`, simply use `tolower` on the right (or both) sides, like so:

```
"b" %in% c("a", "B", "c")
# [1] FALSE

tolower("b") %in% tolower(c("a", "B", "c"))
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

The `searchable` package was created for allowing for various types of searching within objects:

```
l <- list( a=1, b=2, c=3 )
sl <- searchable(l)        # make the list "searchable"
sl <- ignore.case(sl)      # turn on case insensitivity

> sl['B']
$b
[1] 2
```

It works with lists and vectors and does a lot more than simple case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for one set of strings in another set of strings, case insensitively, you could try:

```
s1 = c("a", "b")
s2 = c("B", "C")
matches = s1[ toupper(s1) %in% toupper(s2) ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way of achieving this is to use `str_which(string, pattern)` from the `stringr` package:

```
library("stringr")
str_which(string = tolower(colnames(iris)), pattern = "species")
```