# Using strsplit with multiple separators

Tags: r, strsplit

A character string of interest can either be 'there are five apples' or 'there are five APPLES'

```
  strsplit(string, c('apples', 'APPLES'))
```

So I want to split by either apples or APPLES because I don't know if the string is going to have lower case or uppercase letters. But I tried the code above and it didn't work.

Comment: What do you want to get in your split output ?

Comment: Sorry, bad example. Let me edit. Okay I think this example is a bit better.

Comment: Do you want the search to find the word if lower case or upper case? i.e. the character combination rather than case dependent?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Find the word apple (case insensitive) in the string and then split the string

Comment: Simply convert your string to lowercase first

Comment: Well, that is going to affect the rest of my function. So I can't just convert my string to lowercase

Comment: While not strsplit this may be an approach to solving your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671719/case-insensitive-search-of-a-list-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following  which splits on case-insensitive "apples".

```
x <- 'there are five APPLES in this case'
unlist(strsplit(x, '(?i:apples)', perl=T))
# [1] "there are five " " in this case"
```

Comment: That is interesting, can you explain a bit what just happened here?

Comment: @DavidArenburg The inline `i` (case-insensitive) modifier is placed inside of a non-capturing group. http://regex101.com/r/nL0jN5/1