# TextInput filter in R dataset Shiny

Tags: r, regex, filter, shiny

I'm creating a visualization in Shiny based on the 'movies' dataset. In the dataset, among others, for each movie there is an attribute plot_keywords (format is murder|crime|police|man|detective - 5 words separated with | without spaces). I want to implement an interactive filter for this attribute regardless of uppercase / capital letters - that is, when you enter 'Murder', for example, Shiny should display all movies where 'murder' is present at any part of the plot_keywords attribute. In my code, if the user does not enter anything in the filter box (by default), all movies are displayed. What function should I use after 'else'?

Part of UI code

```
ui <- fluidPage(
fluidRow(
column(3,
    wellPanel(
      textInput("plot", "I want to watch movie about...",NULL)
      )),
```

Part of Server code

```
server <- function(input, output) {
p <- input$plot
m <- movies %>%
filter(
  if(p != NULL) && (p != "")
    {plot_keywords == movies$plot_keywords}
  else
)`
```

Comment: There are a few answers to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671719/case-insensitive-search-of-a-list-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea would be as shown below. This also allows the user to type in multiple words to search for. i.e. when the user types `CrocODile Ii`, the movie `Crocodile Dundee II` will also show up. The `grepl` function that we use has a parameter `ignore.case` to make sure that our query is case insensitive.

Hope this helps!

---

[image]

---

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2movies)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("plot", "I want to watch movie about...",NULL),
  dataTableOutput('my_data')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$my_data <- renderDataTable({
    p <- input$plot
    if(p != '')
      movies %>% filter(Reduce(`&`, lapply(strsplit(p,' ')[[1]], grepl, title,ignore.case=T)))
    else
      movies
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thank you Florian, your answer helped a lot. It works!

Comment: @JohnTown Glad I could help. Oh and by the way, welcome to StackOverflow! ;)